# Batch Changing Google Cloud Storage ACL Permissions

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've been making my files with the follow ACL Attributes through my App Engine that is directly associated with the cloud storage bucket.

```
$options = stream_context_create(['gs'=>['acl'=>'private']]);
```

This is fine if I want to edit and view the files from my App Engine scripts. However, I'd like to be able to access these files from an entirely different Google App Engine Project ID. Or even a Compute Engine.

With the current ACL set to **private**, I realize that this may be impossible.

In my bucket that has these private ACL files, I have the bucket permissions set to owner for my different Project ID, and it works fine with files that aren't set to private.

I was wondering if there was anyway I can *batch* change all of my files in my bucket to the right ACL. I have hundreds of files and it'd be hard to do it 1-by-1. At the moment, if I click on a file and look at it's permissions, there is nothing there (hence private).

---

This is what I get when I just try and get a specific ACL from a file using `gsutil`

```
$ gsutil acl get gs://bucket/file
AccessDeniedException: Access denied. Please ensure you have OWNER permission on gs://bucket/file
```

---

This is what I get when using the `gsutil ch` command to add a user group

```
$ gsutil acl ch -u <project_id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com:W gs://bucket/file
ERROR 0313 15:29:18.896421 retry_decorator.py] Retrying in 1.00 seconds ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/retry-decorator/retry_decorator/retry_decorator.py", line 20, in f_retry
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/acl.py", line 372, in ApplyAclChanges
fields=['acl', 'generation', 'metageneration'])
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 199, in GetObjectMetadata
bucket_name, object_name, generation=generation, fields=fields)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 513, in GetObjectMetadata
generation=generation)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1018, in _TranslateExceptionAndRaise
raise translated_exception
AccessDeniedException: AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
ERROR 0313 15:29:19.995003 retry_decorator.py] Retrying in 2.05 seconds ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/retry-decorator/retry_decorator/retry_decorator.py", line 20, in f_retry
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/acl.py", line 372, in ApplyAclChanges
fields=['acl', 'generation', 'metageneration'])
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 199, in GetObjectMetadata
bucket_name, object_name, generation=generation, fields=fields)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 513, in GetObjectMetadata
generation=generation)
File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1018, in _TranslateExceptionAndRaise
raise translated_exception
AccessDeniedException: AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
```

---

I am assuming I may have to write a php script that runs in my app engine that goes through each file and changes or adds a permission?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

With the ACL set to private, only the AppEngine service account that created the object can modify the ACL.

You will probably have to write a program using [one of the API client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries) and execute it on AppEngine.

Alternatively, I believe the default GCE service account is shared with AppEngine, so if you create a VM with devstorage.full_control scope, I think you should be able to modify the ACL using gsutil inside the VM.

Comment: That's what I figured. Do you know the command off hand that I can use to change the ACL of a file path in the app engine?

Comment: That's plain wrong. I change ACL via gsutil all the time from private to public.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin that only works if you *are* the owner of the object. In this case, the owner is the AppEngine service account, not a user.

Comment: If you authenticate *gsutil*, you can access your objects from any computer on which gsutil has been authenticated. *User* authentication has nothing to do with it.

Comment: No, that is not true. Since the ACL is set to private, you would have to authenticate gsutil as the service account that owns the object in order to change its ACL. In this case, the owner of the object is the AppEngine service account.

Comment: You might be able to modify the ACL if you use gsutil from a GCE VM in the same project, since I believe that also uses the same service account as AppEngine.

Comment: @jterrace I know I can set an ACL with  `stream_context_create()` when creating a file, but do you know any way to modify an ACL in a similar fashion?

Comment: I've also tried using gsutil in GCE and it does not work the way Andrei is saying.

Comment: Guys, I am changing ACL on cloud storage files owned by an App Engine project from my home computer, from my laptop - you can do it from anywhere as long as you know how to authenticate gsutil. And I did dozens of times for multiple App Engine projects over the past 12 months at least. I have no idea why you keep insisting that it cannot be done if the documentation clearly says that it can be.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin - your objects are probably set to an ACL of `project-private` (the default), which allows any owner of the project to modify the ACL. These objects were created as`private`, which *only* allows the owner, in this case the AppEngine service account, to modify the ACL.

Comment: You may be able to start with https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples and instead of using user-authentication, get your access code from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/appidentity/. Then you can iterate over objects (`$storageService->objects->listObjects`) and patch their acls (`$storageService->object->patch`) with `'acl' => NULL` and `'predefinedAcl' => 'projectPrivate'` to replace the ACL with the predefined ACL.

Comment: If you write an example @NathanHerring, I'd love to give you the bounty. Otherwise, overwriting the files is my best course of action.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [gsutil command -acl](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl) to change access rights to all files or only files that match some pattern.

Make sure you authenticate yourself or gsutil won't be able to access your buckets: 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate

Comment: I get the following error on just trying to get the permissions so I doubt this will work, any other suggestions? `$ gsutil acl get gs://bucket/file
AccessDeniedException: Access denied. Please ensure you have OWNER permission on gs://bucket/file`

Comment: You need to authenticate yourself before gsutil can access your buckets: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#authenticate

Comment: You act like I don't have access to my buckets. Of course I am authenticated. Compute engines are immediately authenticated. I just am not the owner of my files from the compute engine.

Comment: Compute engine has nothing to do with it. You can access your objects from any computer as long as you authenticate *your gsutil* (it does not matter if *you* are authenticated). Follow the instructions on the gsutil authentication page, and it will work. I use it all the time.